# Is there a way to wait for data from Firestore before running a second query?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a React App with a Firebase backend.

I have 2 collections, user_roles and branches. I use the user roles data to determine which branches to fetch for the user. For this, I have to begin by fetching the user roles and creating an array of the branches to fetch. I then fetch branches using the code below:

```
const getUserBranchesOnSnapshot = async (branchId) => { //branchId is an array of the user roles 
    const q = query(branchCollection, where(documentId(), 'in', branchId));
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
        const branches = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
            id: doc.id,
            ...doc.data(),
        }));
        setUserBranches(branches);
    }
    );
    return unsubscribe;
}
```

In my component, I do this

```
  //FETCH SPECIFIC BRANCHES
  const fetchuserBranches = async () => {
    try {
      await getUserBranchesOnSnapshot(branchId);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

Then use useEffect:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchuserBranches()
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {}, [branchId]);
```

This gives me the error because it takes some time to get the user roles:

```
FirebaseError: Invalid Query. A non-empty array is required for 'in' filters.
```

I have tried the code below but this keeps reloading the page.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (branchId.length > 0) {
      fetchuserBranches();
    }
  }, [branchId]);
```

This doesnt do anything:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (branchId.length > 0) {
      fetchuserBranches();
    }
  }, []);
```

Please help.

Comment: The error is very clear that the `branchId`  **should be** an **Array** and it **should not be EMPTY**

Comment: In `fetchuserBranches()` method, Where the `branchId ` comes from?

Comment: the branchId is fetched from Firestore, I store the user roles in the branchId array

Comment: What I am asking is `fetchuserBranches()` does not accept any arguments. But you have used `branchId`, Where that `branchId` comes from? Is it from parent scope?

Comment: The fetchUserBranches calls  getUserBranchesOnSnapshot(branchId); which takes  the array as the argument. it is just a function that I use in the component to call the actual getter.